# Is there tab-specific memory?

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to be able to save a small amount on information associated with a tab.  If I reload the same site on that tab, the information is still available to the Javascript, but from another tab it is not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is possible, is called `Session Storage`. According to [MDN](https://docs.w3cub.com/dom/window/sessionstorage/):

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.